# how to enable neocomplcache quick match?

Tags: vim-plugin

I don't know how to enable quick match in the neocomplcache vim plugin. I put

```
let g:neocomplcache_enable_quick_match = 1
```

in my .vimrc, but it's useless. When I press `-` nothing happens.

Answer (score 4):

According to the help file, there is no quick fix feature anymore. You need to use unite for that:

> A: Quick match feature had been removed in latest neocomplcache 
>     because quick match turned into hard to implement.

But you can use |unite.vim| instead to use quick match.

```
imap <expr> -  pumvisible() ? 
    \ "\<Plug>(neocomplcache_start_unite_quick_match)" : '-'
```